Can a method be added to an existing dispinterface?
Generally, a method cannot be added to an existing vtable COM interface or dual COM interface, because there may be a derived interface, so expanding the base interface breaks its layout.
But can a method be added to an existing distpinterface? Will it be potentially disruptive for existing users?
Assume the usual use of distpinterface for events, and the usual use of type library, and out-of-process COM server.

what you really need todo ?

You can always implement IDispatch the way you want, it's fully dynamic. The minimum is GetIDsOfNames->dispid, and a corresponding Invoke(dispid), but if you go cross apartment (cross thread, cross process, cross machine), you'll need a tlb (which you can also implement from IDispatch), however not all clients support this (VB/VBA/VBScript, .NET mostly do for example)

@RbMm, I need to extend the set of possible events fired by a COM server, and need to know if it is possible to edit existing dispinterface to add a new method, or I need a new dispinterface.

@RbMm, the usual out-of-process EXE server. Clients are different. and I don't control all of them. dispinterface (non-vtable, only dispatch) is used for events (that are fired in sever and used by clients). I need to add a new event. Some of clients may need subscribe to the new event I'm adding, but some will keep using only old events without recompilation.

@RbMm, the clients may re-compile, it is just beyond my control. And I'm asking about dispinterface, which doesn't imply vtable entries.

But can a method be added to an existing distpinterface? - yes, simply new unique ID/name. Will it be potentially disruptive for existing users? - no, they simply will be not use this new id/name

If I understand correctly, in your scenario it's the clients that implement the dispinterface, and the server that calls Invoke on them. So the older clients would suddenly have their Invoke implementation called with a DISPID they didn't know existed and weren't prepared to handle. This could theoretically lead to problems - client code could do something like switch (dispid){ case DISPID_Event1: ... case DISPID_Event2: ... default: /* must be Event3 */ } and then have the new Event4 mistaken for Event3

@IgorTandetnik, thanks, this looks like an answer.

as per  Igor Tandetnik comment

If I understand correctly, in your scenario it's the clients that implement the dispinterface, and the server that calls Invoke on them. So the older clients would suddenly have their Invoke implementation called with a DISPID they didn't know existed and weren't prepared to handle. This could theoretically lead to problems -

client code could do something like
switch (dispid){ 
  case DISPID_Event1: ... 
  case DISPID_Event2: ... 
  default: /* must be Event3 */ 
} 

and then have the new Event4 mistaken for Event3
